# Show that $u$ is a measurable function.

Tags: measure-theory

I have the following problem:

> Consider the measure space $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}),\mu)$, and $u:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by:
>
> $$u=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^n}\cdot \mathbb{1}_{[-2^n,2^n]}$$
> *(i)* Show that $u$ is a measurable function i.e. $u\in \mathscr{M}^+(\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$

---

**My attempt:**

Initially my plan is to show that $\mathbb{1}_{[-2^n,2^n]}$ is measurable.

Given a measurable set $A \:\in \:\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$

$$\mathbb{1}^{-1}_{[-2^n,2^n]} (A) =
\begin{cases}
\emptyset,  & 1,0 \notin A \\
\mathbb{R}, & 1,0 \in A \\
[-2^n,2^n], & 1\in A, 0 \notin A \\
[-2^n,2^n]^c, & 1\notin A, 0\in A 
\end{cases}$$

The set $\{ \emptyset, \mathbb{R},[-2^n,2^n],[-2^n,2^n]^c\}$ $\in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ which concludes that $\mathbb{1}_{[-2^n,2^n]}$ is measurable.

But I don't think this is enough.

Comment: You have proved that the indicator functions are measurable, which is a good first step. Now, some ideas for the next steps, as your function $u$ is more complex than just an indicator function: are constant functions measurable? Is the sum of measurable functions measurable? Is the pointwise limit of measurable functions measurable? (Yes! But see to it that you understand these steps if you didn't!)

We would usually write: the sets $\emptyset, \mathbb{R}, [-2^n, 2^n], [-2^n, 2^n]^C$ are Borel sets, or $\{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}, [-2^n, 2^n], [-2^n, 2^n]^C\}\subseteq \beta(\mathbb{R})$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is continuous a.e. (actually, it is locally constant a.e.). More specifically, in all points different from powers of two.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}u^{-1}\left((-\infty,a] \right) :=
  \begin{cases}
                                \emptyset & \text{ if } a \in (-\infty, 0],  \\
                                   (-\infty, -2^m) \cup (2^m, \infty)& \text{ if } a \in \left[\frac{1}{2}3^{-m}, \frac{3}{2}3^{-m}\right) \quad (m=1,2,\ldots), 
\\
\mathbb{R} \text{ if } a \in \left[\frac{1}{2}, \infty\right)
  \end{cases}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $u$ is the pointwise limit of $u_k=\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{3^n}\cdot \mathbb{1}_{[-2^n,2^n]}$ and it's almost trivial that the $u_k$ are measurable: indicator functions of closed intervals are measurable (in fact, they lower-semicontinuous) as is a finite sum of each.